# <Details> element not clickable

Tags: drop-down-menu, html-tag-details, html-tag-summary

I am creating a drop-down menu in line with various online tutorials such as:

https://www.codewall.co.uk/create-a-dropdown-navigation-menu-with-details-summary/

However, when I reproduce this code (including copy-paste), the menu items fail to be clickable. I would like the items (i.e. ) to be clickable links when the  element is expanded.

It might be important that I am using the Cargo website builder, but I have not run into any CSS/HTML/JS issues that couldn't work.

I tried code from multiple sites, as well as typing it myself—it's very simple.

```
<details>
    <summary>
        menu name
    </summary>
        <a href="item 1" rel="history">item 1</a><br>
        <a href="item 2" rel="history">item 2</a><br>
        <a href="item 3" rel="history">item 3</a><br>
        <a href="#">ALL OTHER PIES</a>
</details>
```